# What software can join videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor

What's the best & easiest GUI software that can join a video that I have downloaded in several parts?

Comment: That was my first reaction too, but let's give the user the benefit of the doubt. I'm not voting down but I would recommend editing the question body and stick with the technical aspects of it. The source and content of the videos are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 18):

## [mkvtoolnix-gui](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mkvtoolnix-gui) [image: Install mkvtoolnix-gui]

#### Notes:

- there is no re-encoding involved, so
  the merging process takes only a
  couple of seconds
- it can merge other  video formats,
  like avi, mp4, but the  output is
  always mkv
- it can't merge videos  with different
  apect ratios

For more info see [the documentation here](https://mkvtoolnix.download/docs.html)

[image]

**Quick how-to:**

Click "add", select the first video, then click "append", then select the other videos to append. You can select multiple videos as long as you select them in order or you can append one by one. Then click "Start muxing". You might want to change the output filename. The other options are not really necessary for basic merging. Nevertheless, you can also add multiples subtitles in various formats or languages and also multiple audio tracks.

Comment: I will try after this.

Comment: is this working with other format excluding mkv?

Comment: You can append different formats like avi, but the output is always mkv.

Comment: Didn't work for the divx files I tried to join. In this case avimerge was the better option.

Comment: `mkvmerge -o output.mkv file1.mkv ... fileN.mkv` did it for me

Comment: good but MKV is not always an option...

Comment: Well, for what it is worth, I just firstly converted .mkv to .mp4 and subsequently joined some of the (it is a series called "New Amsterdam") .mp4's into a single video file. So it might still be mkv but a lot of -older- tools (like my samsung tv) will play it as if they are mp4. The software does need a little test, trail and error but works fine and very fast.

Answer (score 8):

### AVI files -  avimerge

**Description**

> avimerge is a  versatile tool.  It can contatenate several
>          AVI files into one. It can also be used to fix an index of
>          a broken file and can also replace audio tracks or muxes
>          new ones. It can read raw AC3 and MP3 files for multplex-
>          ing.

**Installation**

`sudo apt-get install transcode transcode-utils`

**Usage**

You can merge avi files with:

```
avimerge -i input1.avi input2.avi -o output.avi
```

It's encoding-free, so joining the parts usually doesn't take much longer than a minute.

**Options**

Other available options are:

```
Usage: avimerge [options]
     -o file                   output file name
     -i file1 [file2 [...]]    input file(s)
     -p file                   multiplex additional audio track from file
     -a num                    select audio track number from input file [0]
     -A num                    select audio track number in output file [next]
     -b n                      handle vbr audio [autodetect]
     -c                        drop video frames in case audio is missing [off]
     -f FILE                   read AVI comments from FILE [off]
     -x FILE                   read AVI index from FILE [off] (see aviindex(1))
```

Comment: With the input in bash you can specify it like `avimerge -i input{01..10}.avi -o output.avi`, or even `avimerge -i input{01,02,03}.avi -o output.avi` so you don't have to write it a zillion times - this is very useful as I had a few vids on old filesystems spilt up separate files, thanks +1 !

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10: transcode-utils is not available, but `sudo apt-get install transcode` is sufficient

Answer (score 8):

### Mencoder

You can use Mencoder (Mplayer's encoded), that I recently found as a very good alternative to avconv.

**Installation**

`sudo apt-get install mencoder`

**Usage**

To merge some AVI files to a single AVI file, just call mencoder with setting "copy" as both video and audio encoder, so that no encoding is done:

```
mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy video1.avi video2.avi -o mergedvideo.avi
```

With this you can merge not only AVI videos, but also every format supported by Mencoder (see [Selecting codecs and container formats](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-selecting-codec.html) page).

---

Source: [Ubuntu How Tos](http://www.ubuntuhowtos.com/howtos/merge_avi_files_with_mencoder)

Comment: also works with .mov

Comment: I just tried merging avconv-generated H.264-encoded .mov files using MEncoder.  The resulting .mov looked good on Ubuntu but failed to open on a Mac.  (avconv did worse; the merged video looked broken on Ubuntu.)

Comment: The MEncoder documentation (http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-selecting-codec.html) says "Unfortunately, as MEncoder was not designed from the beginning to support container formats other than AVI, your should really be paranoid about the resulting file. Please check to be sure that the audio/video synchronization is OK and that the file can be played correctly by players other than MPlayer."  So it seems that this may not work well for formats other than AVI.

Answer (score 4):

**GNOME Split** :

Very easy to use. Support most used cutting file formats.

[image: GNOME Split]

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-split
```

Comment: this software seems simple & easy to use

Comment: Looks very raw. Videos have metadata. Merging two proper videos without stripping metadata can easily lead to a corrupt video.

Comment: Now available in the main repos.
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gnome%20split

Answer (score 0):

[openshot video editor](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) The one and only. Import videos edit crop and what not.
and export them to any format you want  `mp4`/`flv`/`mkv`/`avi` etc... etc... etc...

to install run these command in gnome-terminal

```
wget https://launchpad.net/openshot/1.4/1.4.2/+download/openshot_1.4.2-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i openshot_1.4.2-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Openshot has "sticky" drag and drop, so dragging the files next to each other on the video timeline will make them completely abut.  The only downside of Openshot is that exporting will cause a re-encode, so it's not light on its feet compared to mkvtoolnix-gui.

Answer (score -1):

PiTiVi is included in current versions of Ubuntu. You can add both file parts to it and then arrange them on the timeline. You then export the video to whatever format you want.

Comment: PiTiVi needs to re-encode the video, which is time consuming for a simple merge procedure.