# How to join an avi video file split in Files as : filename.avi.001, filename.avi.002, filename.avi.003, etc?

Tags: video, avi, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can extract files, name.iso.001 name.iso002 and so on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57212/how-i-can-extract-files-name-iso-001-name-iso002-and-so-on)

Files spitted like that should be joined but they are not just fragments of video, but behave like archives.
How to join them into one and restore the original form of the video?

Comment: Closely related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57212/how-i-can-extract-files-name-iso-001-name-iso002-and-so-on

Comment: @qbi: answers to the question you linked to do **not** say how to concatenate split videos.

Comment: @qbi: maybe a duplicate if the question you mention would have mentioned avi.001-type files, but it doesn't. maybe merging the two questions? i guess my question is the only one mentioning avi.001 files on askubuntu (https://www.google.com/search?q=site:askubuntu.com/questions+avi.001)

Comment: For future reference, if `cat` doesn't work for you try following the steps outlined here (doesn't require transcoding): http://askubuntu.com/a/187679/81372

Comment: will ffsj work here??

Comment: or hjsplit..???

Answer (score 1):

Use the [avimerge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/avimerge.1.html) tool from the [transcode](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/transcode) package.

Comment: See here for more information on how to use it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8523/whats-a-software-that-can-join-videos/187679#187679

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work is

```
cat filename.avi.* > filename.avi
```

Comment: That has never worked for me. Had to [use mencode](http://ubuntuhowtos.com/howtos/merge_avi_files_with_mencoder) instead.

Comment: i was confronted with such files and this line that i googled it worked like magic so i decided to share it but don't know about possible dependencies or other needed conditions

Comment: Whether or not it works depends on how fault-tolerant your player is. It's not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HJSpit to join an avi files.

Go to their website: [HJSplit for Linux](http://www.hjsplit.org/linux/).

Comment: Let's stick to recommending software in the archive, first. Also, your link is broken.