# How to merge all mp4 files in the current directory and its subdirectories into a single mp4 file using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

How to merge all mp4 files in the current directory and its subdirectories into a single mp4 file, preferably in the sequence the files appear when I run the `ls` command in this directory?

Perhaps this can be achieved using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What software can join videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8523/what-software-can-join-videos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first make a list of your mp4 files (`mp4_list.txt`) that are in your current directory and its subdirectories:

```bsh
find "$(pwd)" -type f -name '*.mp4' -printf "file '%p'\n" | tee mp4_list.txt
```

Then use `ffmpeg`'s `concat` demuxer to join all mp4 files in `mp4_list.txt` to an `output.mp4` file:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mp4_list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

I found the above `ffmpeg` command in SuperUser: [Join mp4 files in linux](https://superuser.com/a/521852/1064914)

If you get an error saying `Unsafe file name`, add `-safe 0` before `-i` in the above command. See this Stack Overflow answer: [ffmpeg concat: “Unsafe file name”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029574/3140225)

Comment: You are awesome dude!  It helped me a lot and it became very easy now to manage my files. Thank you!!

Comment: Add "| sort" before " | tee mp4_list.txt" in the first command to have the files in alphabetical order.